# Can someone tell me what this SAS code does?

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS. I am translating SAS code into another language and saw this:

`IF FIRST.VAR THEN VAR1=VAR2;  ELSE VAR1=VAR2*DUM;`

`VAR`, `VAR1`, and `VAR2` are variables in the dataset. `DUM` is not a variable, but a SAS dialect.
Any idea what this DUM does?

I haven't try anything

Comment: DUMMY
DUM
expands variables specified for OPSCORE optimal transformations to dummy variables for the initialization (Tenenhaus and Vachette 1977). By default, the initial values of OPSCORE variables are the actual data values. The dummy variable nominal initialization requires considerable time and memory, so it might not be possible to use the DUMMY option with large data sets. No separate report of the initialization is produced. Initialization results are incorporated into the first iteration displayed in the iteration history table. For details, see the section Optimal Transformations.

Comment: @sergej that is for PROC PRINQUAL, this code is for a data step so not related.

Answer (score 0):

If you only post one line of code without any context there is no way anyone can truly help.

Here is what those two statements mean in a SAS data step.

The FIRST.VAR will exist only if VAR is included in the list of variables in the BY statement.  In which case it will be true on the first observation of the group defined by the current value of VAR.

So for the first observation in the group defined by the value VAR the variable VAR1 is assigned the value of VAR2.  And for any subsequent observations in the group VAR1 is instead assigned the value of VAR2 times DUM.

In that code DUM is the name of a variable.  If the variable does not exist then SAS will create it as a numeric variable and its value will be missing.  If you perform multiplication and at least on the values is missing the result will also be missing.